# Xcode project not working when cloned from remote repository

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have developed an app in Xcode, and I now want to start using GitHub. I was able to successfully push the local project to remote, but when I try to clone the project to another computer and run the project, the project won't work.

When trying to run the workspace, which I usually have to use when editing the project, the .xcodeproj file in the left section of the screen is red, and it is no way to run it. In addition to this, it looks like the framework from the original local project has been left out. Attached is a screenshot where you can see my issue.

I would appreciate any help on this!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSbaG.jpg)

Comment: Is the .xcodeproj file in your file browser?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same location as in the source computer @BlackMagic

Comment: did you 'pod install' on the new computer and then open the workspace file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working. What I had to do was simply deleting the empty (red) .xcodeproj file, go to File -> add files to "...", and manually locate and select the .xcodeproj file in the cloned folder.